# Option not visible for a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a page using bootstrap with the standard CSS. On that page there is a table with a cell where I store the text and a select.
The text and the select are alternative. On click of a button, I'll show one or the other.

The html is this:

```
<td class="tbe" contenteditable="true" style="color: red;">
    <span class="tipo_mov" style="display: none;">Spese casa</span>
    <div class="tipo_mov">
        <select name="tipo_mov">
            <option value="1"> One </option>
            <option value="2"> Two </option>
            <option value="3"> Three </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
```

This is the situation where the select is visible and the text not. In this case if I click on the select I cannot see the options.

This is the js responsible for toggle (from text visible default):

```
$(this).closest('tr')
    .addClass('info')
    .find('.tbe').attr('contenteditable', true)
    .css('color','red')
    .find('.tipo_mov')
    .toggle();
```

Weird thing is that if I turn the select to be visible on page load it works. If I put both to visible on page load it works. 
If I toggle the select to be visible with that JS then select doesn't work anymore.

What did I miss?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.edit').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggle().next('.save').toggle();
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('info').find('.tbe').attr('contenteditable', true).css('color', 'red').find('.tipo_mov').toggle();
    //$(this).closest('tr').find('.tbe').attr('contenteditable', true).css('color','red');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-sm table-hover">
  <thead class="table-inverse">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Data</th>
      <th>Descrizione</th>
      <th>Movimento</th>
      <th>Importo</th>
      <th class="hidden-print">Modifica</th>
      <th class="hidden-print">Cancella</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="id" contenteditable="false">196</td>
      <td class="tbe data" contenteditable="false">01/12/2016</td>
      <td class="tbe descrizione" contenteditable="false">luci natale e interruttore caldaia</td>
      <td class="tbe">
        <span class="tipo_mov">Spese casa</span>
        <div class="tipo_mov" style="display: none;">
          <select name="tipo_mov">
            <option value="1">Incasso fattura</option>
            <option value="2">Spese banca</option>
            <option value="3">Affitto casa</option>
            <option value="4">Rimborso debiti</option>
            <option value="5">Viaggi</option>
            <option value="6">Interessi Attivi</option>
            <option value="7">Consulenze</option>
            <option value="8">Costi auto</option>
            <option value="9">Cassa per nota spese</option>
            <option value="10">Nota spese</option>
            <option value="11">Alimentari</option>
            <option value="12">Carburante</option>
            <option value="13">Finanziamento soci</option>
            <option value="14">Saldo Carta di Credito</option>
            <option value="15">Regali</option>
            <option value="16">Abbigliamento</option>
            <option value="17" selected="">Spese casa</option>
            <option value="18">Consumi</option>
            <option value="19">Libri & Abbonamenti & Co</option>
            <option value="20">Pranzi & Cene</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="tbe importo" contenteditable="false">45,00</td>
      <td class="hidden-print" contenteditable="false">
        <button class="btn btn-primary edit" data-num="196" type="button" aria-label="Left Align">
          <button class="btn btn-success save" style="display: none;" data-num="196" type="button" aria-label="Left Align">
      </td>
      <td class="hidden-print" contenteditable="false"></td>
    </tr>
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uygvd74t/1/).

Comment: I think you should be adding `contenteditable` to the span, not the whole `td`.

Comment: could you provide a working snippet ?

Comment: Yes, actually the contenteditable is useless there. It's a inline editor. In case of that value instead of editing the text in the span you have to choose an option on the select

Comment: @Deep yes, was working on that. Updated the question. Same behaviour as in my app

Comment: @LelioFaieta i am not able to replicate the select not working scenario. could you update your example for that?

Comment: FYI, works in Chrome but not Firefox. A clue?

Comment: @Deep can you try on Firefox? The fiddle behaves as per my question on that browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the contenteditable on select element on firefox. Since contenteditable property is inherited from parent if the no contenteditable property is set on the element, when you set the contenteditable true for the div same sets true for it. While chrome handles this scenario elegantly but firefox not.

You can either remove contenteditable from div itself or set the contenteditable to false in the select element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.edit').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggle().next('.save').toggle();
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('info').find('.tbe').attr('contenteditable', true).css('color', 'red').find('.tipo_mov').toggle();
    //$(this).closest('tr').find('.tbe').attr('contenteditable', true).css('color','red');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-sm table-hover">
  <thead class="table-inverse">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Data</th>
      <th>Descrizione</th>
      <th>Movimento</th>
      <th>Importo</th>
      <th class="hidden-print">Modifica</th>
      <th class="hidden-print">Cancella</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="id" contenteditable="false">196</td>
      <td class="tbe data" contenteditable="false">01/12/2016</td>
      <td class="tbe descrizione" contenteditable="false">luci natale e interruttore caldaia</td>
      <td class="tbe">
        <span class="tipo_mov">Spese casa</span>
        <div class="tipo_mov" style="display: none;">
          <select name="tipo_mov" contenteditable="false">
            <option value="1">Incasso fattura</option>
            <option value="2">Spese banca</option>
            <option value="3">Affitto casa</option>
            <option value="4">Rimborso debiti</option>
            <option value="5">Viaggi</option>
            <option value="6">Interessi Attivi</option>
            <option value="7">Consulenze</option>
            <option value="8">Costi auto</option>
            <option value="9">Cassa per nota spese</option>
            <option value="10">Nota spese</option>
            <option value="11">Alimentari</option>
            <option value="12">Carburante</option>
            <option value="13">Finanziamento soci</option>
            <option value="14">Saldo Carta di Credito</option>
            <option value="15">Regali</option>
            <option value="16">Abbigliamento</option>
            <option value="17" selected="">Spese casa</option>
            <option value="18">Consumi</option>
            <option value="19">Libri & Abbonamenti & Co</option>
            <option value="20">Pranzi & Cene</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="tbe importo" contenteditable="false">45,00</td>
      <td class="hidden-print" contenteditable="false">
        <button class="btn btn-primary edit" data-num="196" type="button" aria-label="Left Align">
          <button class="btn btn-success save" style="display: none;" data-num="196" type="button" aria-label="Left Align">
      </td>
      <td class="hidden-print" contenteditable="false"></td>
    </tr>
```